# VLC install error?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, software-installation, vlc

Tried to reinstall VLC but I keep getting the fellowing message:

[image: vlc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not comment on posts yet, I only have enough "rep" to answer questions. As such, this is a suggestion.

Open terminal: CTRL-ALT-T

try running:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This should try to resolve any dependency issues.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I used the above and got message to remove some unused packages, did that using autoremove, then restarted my laptop and retried and it installed.